# How to find MB disk size and create list of variables

Tags: batch-file, command, wmi

I'm trying to automate the re-partitioning of many machines using easus command line utility.
I can make batch files but I think I'm out of my depth when playing with wmi.

My Goal is to find the size in MB of both The C and D partitions and place them in a txt file.
After that I want to do some basic maths, where I take 60gb from D and give it to C. C is currently around 20gb and I want to increase it to 80gb.

Something like:

```
Find C Size: Cs
Find D Size: Ds
Find D Free: Df
```

Is sufficient space available in Df to resize 60010mb smaller.

```
If yes than Ds - 60005mb = Ds1

Cs+60005 = Cs1
Ds-60005 = DS1
```

Run easus command 1 (this resizes d to start 60005mb after c, and finnish 5mb before the end of the drive.

```
epmconsole.exe resize --disk=0 --volume=1 --start=Cs1 --size=Ds1 -r
```

Run easus command 2
Run epmconsole.exe" resize --disk=0 --volume=0 --start=0 --size=80000 -r

(I'm guessing that the 10mb will allow the easus command line to function without error due small partition boundary issues)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it _should_ work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0):

Get the size of a drive and place it in a text file (batch script):

```
drive=c:
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%n in ('fsutil volume diskfree %drive% ^| find /i "avail free bytes"') do echo %%n > your_text_file.txt
```

'set /a' math is limited to 32bits (4GB in HDD terms) so it is not suited to your purposes. Best use something else for the math. VBscript can do it. If you must use a batch script, you can use a windows compiled version of 'bc' [downloadable at sourceforge](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/). Google 'bc syntax' for more.